# How to make a container width sync dynamically with its content? flutter

Tags: flutter, containers

So i wanna achieve this [image: design]

i have tried to use Wrap but it doesn't show like this. anyone know how to make it look like this?

code

```
Wrap(
              children: [
                GridView(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 100,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisExtent: 40,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                  ),
                  children: [
                    ReviewWidget('Tempat tidak sesuai dengan foto'),
                    ReviewWidget('Tempat tidak ditemukan'),
                    ReviewWidget('Tailor tidak dapat ditemui'),
                    ReviewWidget('tidak sesuai dengan foto'),
                    ReviewWidget('tailor jele'),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

the result :

[image: container is not sync with the content]

Comment: could you please add you code too?

Comment: so what's wrong with `Wrap`? the image you posted is what`Wrap` renders it's children

Comment: my apologize, i already add my code

Comment: the text is not show entirely like the example

Comment: can you set the property mainAxisSize ?

Comment: there is no property mainAxisSize

Comment: is this because i use grid view?

Answer (score 0):

the GridView force its children to be on a default aspect ratio so it's children take the same space on the screen

based on what I understood that you want the widgets to take space based on it's content, so there is no need for gridView here, just use `Wrap` and wrap your children widget with it :

```
Wrap(
          children: [
                ReviewWidget('Tempat tidak sesuai dengan foto'),
                ReviewWidget('Tempat tidak ditemukan'),
                ReviewWidget('Tailor tidak dapat ditemui'),
                ReviewWidget('tidak sesuai dengan foto'),
                ReviewWidget('tailor jele'),
          ],
        ),
```

and make sure that ReviewWidget isn't constrained with a hardcoded width and height, so it will take the size of the content widget

you can add also add padding to that widget if you need it, Ex:

```
Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10), child: ReviewWidget())
```

Hope this helps